# console.log(enum) : results in undefined + Typescript & Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Here is the code for the file containing the enum:

```
    module mops {
        export enum Status {
            OK = 0,
            ROC = (1 << 0),
            LLA = (1 << 1),
            LOA = (1 << 2),
            HIA = (1 << 3),
            HHA = (1 << 4),
            MNL = (1 << 5),
            OFS = (1 << 6),
            INV = (1 << 7),
            BAD = (1 << 8),
            IOF = (1 << 9),
            LLL = (1 << 10),
            HHH = (1 << 11),
            LOR = (1 << 12),
            AVG = (1 << 13),
            SUS = (1 << 14),
            PND = (1 << 16),
            MXT = (1 << 17),
            INC = BAD | INV | OFS | IOF,
            IGNORE = BAD | INV | OFS | IOF | MXT,
            MASK = ROC | LLA | LOA | HIA | HHA | MNL | OFS | INV | BAD | IOF | LLL | HHH | LOR | AVG | SUS | PND | MXT
        }
    }
```

Here is the code testing to print the enum from another file:

```
/// <reference path="../../enum.ts" />
module mops {
    import x = mops.Status;

    console.log("testing", x);

    for (let i in x)
        console.log("Member: ", i);
}
```

When ran, the console would print "testing undefined".
I have tried "export declare enum Status" (Status is undefined) or "export const enum Status" (gives error). I need to understand what I am doing wrong.

This is a python project in Visual Studio fyi if that is helpful in anyway.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have your code set up to output two JavaScript files, but have only included the second file in your script tags. Include both files in script tags, or use the `outFile` option to concatenate the files together.